# React Router match object null response issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm trying to determine why i can't use a ternary operator with match in react router to determine when match is null.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Resource = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Test {match != '' ? match.params.id : "no match!" }</h3>
    </div>
  )
};

const jsx = (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/FandA">Finishes And Accessories</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/CO">Complete Order</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/Re">Resources</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/:id" component={Resource}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The routing works fine for /FandA, /CO, and /Re. But it doesn't match null in the ternary operator for /

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Router 4 the **match** prop is of type object and not string. You are expecting it to be matched route but it is not the case. **match** prop is a object like this:

```
{
    "path": "/:id",
    "url": "/FandA",
    "isExact": true,
    "params": {}
}
```

Hence your ternary condition should be:

```
(match.params && match.params.id) ? match.params.id : "no match!"
```

Or It can be simplified to:

```
match.params.id || "no match!"
```

Refere to this link for more detailed description:
[React router **match** help](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

Comment: Hi Hriday, thank you for the response. However, I'm still having the same issue. The reason I was checking against '' is because when I looked at the Route in React Tools, it shows match: null (i tried null as well). I took a screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kgl261refu60po/null.png?dl=0

Comment: @Chadimoglou, route you mentioned will match only if id paramaeter is present and not if you are at Home route. You have to make it optional parameter to allow it to match even on Home route. 
Consider this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/olkxr0mppz

As far as null match is concerned it shouldn't happen if you use React Router 4, Please check React Router's version.

To understand null match please go through this documentation: 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match/null-matches